# playframework use find with IN and a list of models

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework, playframework-1.x

I've got a problem with the following code, written in play (1.2.4):

```
List<MSprache> sprachen = MSprache.find("active = ?", true).fetch();
List<MFieldDscr> textey     = MFieldDscr.find("sprache IN", sprachen).fetch();
```

And if I execute a test, which tests this part of code, the following Error displays:

```
A java.lang.IllegalArgumentException has been caught, org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: null near line 1, column 48 [from models.Sprache.MFieldDscr where sprache IN]
```

I don't understand where the mistake is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure about what you're trying to achieve,
but I think this is what you want:

```
String jpql = "FROM MFieldDescr fd WHERE fd.sprache "
            + "IN ( SELECT s FROM MSprache s WHERE s.active = ? ) ";
List<MFieldDscr> textey = MFieldDescr.find( jpql, true ).fetch();
```

This will find all the `MFieldDescr` entities which have a `MSprache` with active set to `true`.

---

The language used to query entities is JPQL by the way, in case you want to learn more about it.

Here are some useful links:

- [JPQL In Expressions](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.0/apache-openjpa-1.2.0/docs/manual/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_in)
- [JPQL Subqueries](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.0/apache-openjpa-1.2.0/docs/manual/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_subqueries)

Comment: no that wasn't realy that what i meaned. The problem wasn't to make an JPQL like this... I thought that it's possible to use the 'IN' Syntax and give a list with any type and the model understand what i meaned ;)

Comment: Have you tried `MFieldDscr.find("sprache IN ?", sprachen).fetch();` (with the missing question mark) ?

Comment: yes i get the same error :( is also tried to make it only with the ids of the model...

Comment: Weird... Try creating the query with the entity manager, like so: `String jpql = "SELECT fd FROM MFieldDescr fd WHERE fd.sprache IN :sprachen"; 
Query q = em.createQuery(jpql, MFieldDescr.class);
q.setParameter("sprachen", sprachen);
List<MFieldDescr> result = q.getResultList();`

Comment: hm, with your last code, i get the result i expect... I don't understand the problem. It can't be a solution to make such "complicated"...

Comment: This is just the normal way you would use jpa. It's weird `find()` doesn't work (didn't work for me either), because this should be what it does internally...